# Resolving Beyond Bounds Error in iOS

Tags: ios, debugging, nsrangeexception

An app I'm working is crashing due to an out of bounds error - I should be able to figure out why however the output console does not show which array in the code is causing the crash - does anyone have any ideas on how I can find out.

```
    2013-09-17 11:14:15.639 TestApp[5970:11303] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Thanks

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. You are trying to get the 0 item out of an array that is empty. This is what the error is saying.

Comment: Put the exception break point and find the crashing line

Comment: But where do i put the exception break point?

Comment: Ok got it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html